# How to add the Facebook Messenger Customer Chat Plugin to your site using Google Tag Manager

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to install the [Facebook Messenger Customer Chat Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin) onto my website using Google Tag Manager so that it can be controlled by non-developers, however after creating a 'Custom HTML' block in GTM, it is rejecting the tag saying that the HTML is invalid.

This code works fine when added manually, but not when used inside GTM:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK MESSENGER CHAT BOX -->
<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="xxxxxxxxxx"></div>
<script>
  // Initialise Facebook SDK
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'xxxxxxxxxxx', // Facebook App ID goes here
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And the error:

> Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found in template.

What's the workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that GTM doesn't like something about the HTML (probably the `page_id` attribute). So, instead, the `<div>` needs to be created dynamically using JavaScript. This is the final code we used:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK MESSENGER CHAT BOX -->
<script>
  // We create the DIV dynamically to work correctly with Tag Manager
  var chatDiv = document.createElement('div');
  chatDiv.className = 'fb-customerchat';
  chatDiv.setAttribute('page_id', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // Facebook Page ID goes here
  document.body.appendChild(chatDiv);

  // Initialise Facebook SDK
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Facebook App ID goes here
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!