# Google Tag Manager + Facebook Messenger not working

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager, facebook-application

I try to implent the [Facebook Messenger code](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111390/how-to-add-the-facebook-messenger-customer-chat-plugin-to-your-site-using-google) to my GTM.

After importing and changing, it doesn't show up. Can anyone see whats wrong with my code?

Code:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK MESSENGER CHAT BOX -->
<script>
  // We create the DIV dynamically to work correctly with Tag Manager
  var chatDiv = document.createElement('div');
  chatDiv.className = 'fb-customerchat';
  chatDiv.setAttribute('page_id', '1417984138420288'); // Facebook Page ID goes here
  document.body.appendChild(chatDiv);

  // Initialise Facebook SDK
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '276246456505554', // Facebook App ID goes here
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

A screenshot of the GTM
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you viewed the page source to verify your code is actually present? Did you check the developer console to see if there were any errors?

Comment: I edit my post, and insert a screenshot.

Comment: Oke, just saw that i need to change the url: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js to https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js. But it's still not working. (even changed it in my 1st post).

Comment: See on StackOverflow: [Refused to display… frame-ancestors https://www.facebook.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736650/refused-to-display-frame-ancestors-https-www-facebook-com)

Comment: You need to add your site's domain name to facebook settings, otherwise anybody could use your fb messenger account.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into the Facebook Page Settings and change the Location and Age restrictions to All, otherwise when it tries to check if you are in the right country or older than 18 and can't access that info due to some users privacy or logged in settings, it just defaults to not displaying the messenger bubble.