# How to set the default language for Facebook Messenger Chat Plugin for users not logged into Facebook?

Tags: google-tag-manager, translation, facebook-application

I've been using [this tip](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111390/how-to-add-the-facebook-messenger-customer-chat-plugin-to-your-site-using-google?answertab=votes#tab-top) in order to add Facebook Messenger Chat Plugin on a website via Google Tag Manager, and it's working (many thanks!)

But when the visitor is not connected to his Facebook account, the welcome phrase is in English. The other translations managed through the Facebook app are working correctly when you are connected to Facebook.

I'm really not into code, but I changed this:

[image]

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

into that:

```
 js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js";
```

with no effect.